# PHP Object + Do/While

Tags: php

Using the Amazon Product API, I'm trying to get all the subcategories to get to the root of a product category.

**Manually**

For example:

Seeking the root category of a SanDisk 8Gb microSD

```
echo $response->Items->Item->BrowseNodes->BrowseNode->Name;
echo $response->Items->Item->BrowseNodes->BrowseNode->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Name;
echo $response->Items->Item->BrowseNodes->BrowseNode->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Ancestors->BrowseNode->Ancestors->BrowseNode->IsCategoryRoot;
```

Print:

```
Tarjetas microSD
Tarjetas de memoria
TRUE
```

The last line shows **true** because it has gotten to the root category.

**Automatic (don´t work)**

```
$i = 0;
do {
$i++;
$ancestors = 'Ancestors->BrowseNode->';
$repeat[$i] = str_repeat($ancestors, $i) . 'IsCategoryRoot';
$categoriavar[$i] = $response->Items->Item->BrowseNodes->BrowseNode->{$repeat[$i]};
echo $i;
var_dump($categoriavar[$i]);
} while (!isset($categoriavar[$i]));
```

Print:

```
1NULL
2NULL
3NULL
4NULL
5NULL
Continues...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP object property notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23196959/php-object-property-notation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$i = 0;
$temp = $response->Items->Item->BrowseNodes->BrowseNode;

do{
   $i++;
   $categoriacar[$i] = $temp->Ancestors->BrowseNode->IsCategoryRoot;
   $temp = $temp->Ancestors->BrowseNode;
   echo $i;
   var_dump($categoriavar[$i]);
}while($categoriacar[$i] != 'TRUE')
```